# SELECT the largest 2 rows on column_a where column_b=1

Tags: mysql, max

How to get complete row of the 2 greatest numbers on column_a
where column_b=1?

Tried this, (it returns a syntax error) :

`SELECT *, GREATEST (`id`) -(or column_a) -
FROM table
WHERE column_b = '1'
LIMIT 2;`

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option would be to add an `ORDER BY` clause, e.g.

```
SELECT t.*
  FROM table t
 WHERE t.column_b = '1'
 ORDER BY t.column_a DESC
LIMIT 2
```

That will get you two rows that have the largest ("greatest") values of `column_a`.

(The question asks about "2 greatest numbers on column_a", but the OP query doesn't have any reference to column_a.)

Comment: Thanks - (made note : 'column_a' is 'id'... thanks simple solution was thinking needed MAX or GREATEST...

Answer (score 2):

If you can use LIMIT (as you are doing) it's pretty straightforward, just let MySQL do the work:

```
SELECT
*

FROM
table

WHERE
column_b = '1'

ORDER BY
id DESC

LIMIT 2
```

Comment: Thanks your answer works also! it's basically the same as @spencer's easier to read...

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MAX(id) as maxID, column_a, column_b, column_c 
FROM table 
WHERE column_c = '1';
```

Comment: Thanks, LIMIT seems to do nothing...getting only one row!?

Comment: Whoops. Yeah Max() will only bring one row. My mistake.